# How to call routechangesuccess event manually without calling the $location.path

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am in a scenario, where my visual studio solution contains two projects one is angularjs application(main) and another project is MVC project. We used virtualpath provider mechanism to show MVC project's related pages into angularjs application. Now we are able to access both angularjs and MVC application related urls. But we are facing some problems while we are doing that,

we are differentiating urls between angularjs and MVC project related urls by comparing the "/#" position in incoming url within $locationchnagestart event. When we access MVC project related url, it is showing up the appropriate page but at the end of the requested url it is adding default angularjs app route

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
....
$routeProvider.otherwise({       
        redirectTo: function () {
                return '/default';
        }
    });
}]);
```

since no route was found it is taking otherwise block and adding default route bit to the url like,

> http://localhost:88/MvcHome/Index#/default

In order to remove that default route from the url, we have tried like,

```
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if(IsMvcUrl){  
      event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

It is working fine it is removing that default route bit from the requested url.
But it is not calling routechangesuccess event since we are stopping propagation at the locationchangestart itself.

We need routechangesuccess event to be called to perform some application related operation,

```
 $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (a, b, c) {
            DoOperation(a, b, c);
  });
```

I have tried by broadcasting the routechangesuccess event with in the locationchangestart event, but it is not working properly due to wrong parameter passing.

Is there any possible way where we can call routechangesuccess event manually with proper parameter passing and without calling the $location.path('some url') within the locationchangestart event. Please guide me.